# Cannot create PDF by ggplot2 within if-statements

Tags: r, if-statement, pdf, ggplot2, graphics

Consider a minimal example: generating an empty plot with ggplot2 and put it into a PDF file. Typically people would do

```
pdf()
ggplot()
dev.off()
```

and it works as expected. However, when you wrap these statements into an if-statement, the resulting PDF file becomes corrupted.

```
if (TRUE) {
    pdf()
    ggplot()
    dev.off()
}
```

[image]

This issue has been reproduced on both Windows 10 and macOS Mojave. I'm using the latest version of R

```
$ R --version
R version 3.6.0 (2019-04-26) -- "Planting of a Tree"
Copyright (C) 2019 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin18.6.0 (64-bit)

R is free software and comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY.
You are welcome to redistribute it under the terms of the
GNU General Public License versions 2 or 3.
For more information about these matters see
https://www.gnu.org/licenses/.
```

Comment: use `ggsave` to save `ggplot` - I think that should be the typical approach.

Comment: I think this usually happens when you are missing a `dev.off()`. Maybe be from a `pdf()` executed before the `ifelse` statement.

Comment: @Suren Using `ggsave` works!  However,  I have a `dev.off()` in the if-statement. BTW before each experiment I have `rm(lisy=ls())` to make sure the environment is clean.

Comment: I think you have to do something like this `p <- ggplot(); print(p)` then `dev.off()`

Comment: Yeah, only the last statement in `{}` (here `dev.off()`) gets implicitly printed, so you need to explicitly print: `if (TRUE) { pdf(); print(ggplot()); dev.off()}`

Comment: I see: one has to explicitly print the plot to use something like `pdf()`.

Answer (score 1):

To save a `ggplot` object using `pdf` or `jpg` functions, one has to explicitly print the ggplot.

```
if (TRUE) { 
  pdf() 
  print(ggplot()) 
  dev.off()
}
```

This is stated in [R-FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-do-lattice_002ftrellis-graphics-not-work_003f) **7.22 Why do lattice/trellis graphics not work?**

> The most likely reason is that you forgot to tell R to display the graph. Lattice functions
>   such as xyplot() create a graph object, but do not display it (the
>   same is true of ggplot2 graphics, and Trellis graphics in S-PLUS). The
>   print() method for the graph object produces the actual display. When
>   you use these functions interactively at the command line, the result
>   is automatically printed, but in source() or inside your own functions
>   you will need an explicit print() statement.

So, it would **not save** if one simply `source` a script even in the absence of a conditional statement or loop (`source` with `echo = TRUE` would save the plot).

---

I personally prefer to use the `ggsave` function since it seems more flexible.

```
if (TRUE) { 
  ggplot() 
  ggave(filename = "plot.pdf")
}
```